# Find remaining angles and sides of a pyramid

Tags: geometry

I have a pyramid with corners on the base **ABCD** and point **E**, turned on its side.
The face **ABE** is horizontal, the edges **BC** and **AD** are both vertical. So angles **DAE**, **DAB**, **CBA**, and **CBE** are all 90°

The angles on the bottom face are known: **ABE** = 18.0975°, **AEB** = 119.1375°, and **BAE** = 42.765°
The edge lengths of the top face are also known: **DE** = 554, **CD** = 1560, **CE** = 1214

[image: Diagram of the pyramid]

I can calculate the internal angles for that top face using the edge lengths.
**DCE** ≈ 18.09°, **CDE** ≈ 42.87°, and **CED** ≈ 119.04°
This makes sense to me, angle **DCE** is slightly smaller than **ABE** because both **D** and **E** are below it. Likewise angle **CDE** is slightly larger because **D** is the middle height, and **CED** is smaller because **E** is the lowest height (0 height).

That's about where I get stuck. I feel like this should be enough to calculate the heights of **C** and **D** using the difference between their angles and their pairs on the horizontal below, but I can't figure out how to go about doing that.

Are the remaining edge lengths solvable with this much information? Would it become solvable if I had the height for one of **AD** or **BC** or the horizontal distance between them?

**EDIT**

I've realized my method of measuring angles for my original numbers was introducing a lot of inaccuracy to the system. Enough that I've since discovered an impossible triangle elsewhere. I still wonder about how to solve the basic problem, but if those particular numbers are impossible then these should represent a shape that can actually definitely exist:
$
DE = 100 \\
CD = 138 \\
CE = 150 \\
\angle ABE = 47.22° \\
\angle AEB = 78.14° \\
\angle BAE = 54.64°
$

With the remaining numbers (solution) being these:
$
\begin{align*}
AE &= 90 \\
BE &= 100 \\
AD &= 10\sqrt{19} &\approx &43.6 \\
BC &= 50\sqrt{5} &\approx &111.8 \\
AB &= 2\sqrt{1161+250\sqrt{95}} &\approx &120.
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Is the rectangular base $ABCD$ in fact a square ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Can't be a square, since $AD$ is shorter than hypotenuse $DE=554$, while another side $CD = 1560$.

Comment: Is the base $ABCD$ in fact a right trapezium, not given to be a rectangle? Because you mentioned "the heights of **C** and **D**" and "the height for one of **AD** or **BC**".

Comment: @peterwhy yes. The line *CD* might be close to horizontal, as the distance across is quite a bit larger than the expected height difference, but the heights are indeed different.

Comment: point A, B and E are co planer (on one plane) ,how the sum of angles of triangle ABE can be more than 180 degrees?

Comment: @sirous Most likely I've made a rounding error or a typo somewhere. Which angles are you looking at? 18.0975+119.1375+42.765=180 (original) and 47.22+78.14+54.64=180 (edit)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: AB=CD, knowing angles of triangle ABE, you can find BE and AE using sine rule.In right angled triangles BCE and ADE knowing measures  of sides you can find the angles. Use following figures for estimation. The software I used has rounded the measures.

figure 1:

[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

Figure 3:

[image]